# Create var based on list in dict

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Imagine this dict on 4 different hosts.

```yaml
# on host 1
my_dict:
  ip: 10.0.0.111
  roles:
    - name: something
      observer: false

# on host 2
my_dict:
  ip: 10.0.0.112
  roles:
    - name: something
      observer: false

# on host 3
my_dict:
  ip: 10.0.0.113
  roles:
    - name: something
      observer: true

# on host 4
my_dict:
  ip: 10.0.0.114
  roles:
    - name: whatever
```

When Ansible runs for all 4 hosts I want it to build a variable for each host having the roles name 'something'. The desired output is:

```yaml
10.0.0.111 10.0.0.112 10.0.0.113:observer
```

There are 2 requirements:

- when my_dict.roles.name == 'something' it must add the ip to the var
- but when my_dict.roles.observer , it must add the ip + ':observer'

I eventually want to use the var in a Jinja template, so to me, the var can be either set via an Ansible task or as a jinja template.

This doesn't work:

```yaml
- name: set fact for ip
  debug:
    msg: >-
      {{ ansible_play_hosts |
      map('extract', hostvars, ['my_dict', 'ip'] ) |
      join(' ') }}
  when: ???
```

Comment: Why would your variables and task give `10.0.0.111 10.0.0.112 10.0.0.113:observer` with the provided example?  Is `observer` the variable name and `true` or `false` the values, and you're trying to run a command on hosts that have that variable set?  I'm admittedly confused as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't understand your question. But i'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the variable is being constructed for as well.  My guess is to template a configuration file for a cluster of some type where hosts take on some type of persona based upon the variable.

Comment: Benoit, that was a copy/paste mistake. And Joe, yes, your guess is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create two lists:

- one with what should be postfixed to the IPs with the condition based on the `observer` property
- the other one with the IPs

And then zip them back together.

Given:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{ 
        _ips | zip(_is_observer) | map('join') | join(' ')
      }}
  vars:
    _hosts: >-
      {{ 
        hostvars 
        | dict2items 
        | selectattr('key', 'in', ansible_play_hosts)
        | selectattr('value.my_dict.roles.0.name', '==', 'something')
      }}
    _is_observer: >-
      {{ 
        _hosts
        | map(attribute='value.my_dict.roles.0.observer') 
        | map('replace', false, '') 
        | map('replace', true, ':observer')
      }}
    _ips: >-
      {{
        _hosts
        | map(attribute='value.my_dict.ip')
      }}
```

This yields:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: 10.0.0.111 10.0.0.112 10.0.0.113:observer
```

Comment: That should do, and it has been DRY'ed

Comment: I love these answers. I really have to learn how to do this stuff.

Comment: Simple question, can I also easily configure it, so that when 'observer: true' that IP omitted  from the list, the result would then be: '10.0.0.111 10.0.0.112'

Comment: Sure, a list without the observer(s) would be `"{{ _hosts | selectattr('value.my_dict.roles.0.observer') }}"` which is a short version of `"{{ _hosts | selectattr('value.my_dict.roles.0.observer', '==', true) }}"`